# unreadable characters in buffer and bars

Tags: fonts

I have installed emacs 24.3 from source on CentOS 6.9.

I configured, compiled and installed it with:

./configure --prefix=$HOME/install --with-xpm=no --with-gif=no --with-tiff=no
make 
make install

The unreadable characters appear in the bottom bars as well as the buffers.

Same issue with emacs-24.5

[image]

Comment: Since you're installing from source anyways, is there a reason you're using version 24 instead of the latest version, 26?

Comment: The error message looks like something related to faces. Do you have any init file? Have you tried running `emacs-Q`? If the error persists, please copy it and add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As DoMiNeLA10 suggested, it was related to faces in my init file. Removing that solved the problem in my system.

The line causing the issue was:
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Menlo" :height 120)